# How to animate a transition between 3 or more view controllers with buttons in SWIFT 3?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button, segue

I'm relatively new in programming and currently try to build an app with three (if possible more) view controllers. I did a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9sH_VxPPo4&t=505s) in which I learned to animate between two view controllers after pressing a custom button. This all worked perfectly.

But now I try to implement another view controller (ThirdViewController) and a second button (showThirdVCButton).

The transitioning works perfectly for both buttons but the animation is set back to the standard animation.

This is my code in the initial view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var showSecondVCButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var showThirdVCButton: UIButton!


let transition = CircularTransition()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //I customise my buttons here
    showSecondVCButton.layer.cornerRadius = showSecondVCButton.frame.size.width / 2
    showThirdVCButton.layer.cornerRadius = showSecondVCButton.frame.size.width / 2
}

//The destination for each button is declared here and the animation style
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "secondVCSegue" {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
        secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    }

    if segue.identifier == "thirdVCSegue" {
        let thirdVC = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
        thirdVC.transitioningDelegate = self
        thirdVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    }

}


func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    transition.transitionMode = .present

    if showSecondVCButton.isTouchInside == true {
        transition.startingPoint = showSecondVCButton.center
        transition.circleColor = showSecondVCButton.backgroundColor!
    }

    if showThirdVCButton.isTouchInside == true {

        transition.startingPoint = showThirdVCButton.center
        transition.circleColor = showThirdVCButton.backgroundColor!
    }

    return transition
}


func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.transitionMode = .dismiss

    if showSecondVCButton.isTouchInside == true {
        transition.startingPoint = showSecondVCButton.center
        transition.circleColor = showSecondVCButton.backgroundColor!
    }

    if showThirdVCButton.isTouchInside == true {

        transition.startingPoint = showThirdVCButton.center
        transition.circleColor = showThirdVCButton.backgroundColor!
    }

    return transition
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint inside the `if segue.identifier == "thirdVCSegue" { ... }` code to make sure you're getting there? An error in the segue's identifier could prevent that code from running...

Answer (score 1):

huberdo - I followed the same tutorial you were looking at, and I was able to replicate the error you're getting, when I copied the second button rather than creating one from scratch.  Have a look and check that you only have one segue for each button.

I think you can simplify the code.  I would always prefer to set up an action for the buttons, so that you can see in your code where things are being called - what you have just now is a combination of Storyboard setup and explicit code.

If you use actions for the buttons, and set a flag to keep track of which button is pressed, it all becomes a lot simpler

```
var transition = CircularTransition()
var startingView = UIView()  // this will define the starting point for all transitions

//
//
// explicit actions for the buttons
@IBAction func cmdOneAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    startingView = sender as! UIView
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueShow1", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func cmdTwoAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    startingView = sender as! UIView
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueShow2", sender: self)
}
```

Simplified animation functions

```
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    transition.transitionMode   = .present
    transition.startingPoint    = startingView.center
    transition.circleColor      = startingView.backgroundColor!

    return transition
}


func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    transition.transitionMode   = .dismiss        
    transition.startingPoint    = startingView.center
    transition.circleColor      = startingView.backgroundColor!

    return transition
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I adopted the code to your suggested one but the animation is still set to basic. The transmission works fine. There might something be in my `if segue.identifier == "" {`  ?

Comment: Probably.  If you can't match the segue identifier - and you won't if you're checking for "" - so it will always run the default version

Comment: Thank you Russel! Nice there are people like you :) Have a nice day!